# ffmpeg still not working on heroku [discord.py]

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I have tried all the methods I found on Internet. Here is the screenshot of my heroku builds:
[image]

Here are the modules I imported:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import itertools
import math
import random
import discord
import youtube_dl
from async_timeout import timeout
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
```

This is the `requirements.txt` file:

```
discord.py
PyNaCl==1.3.0
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
python-dotenv
youtube_dl
```

And I get the following in the heroku logs:

```
2021-01-04T17:29:40.235769+00:00 app[worker.1]: ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libvpx.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Where is the problem

Comment: does this run on your computer, not on Heroku?

Comment: try this build pack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-activestorage-preview

Comment: @benl134 Yes it runs fine from my pc. After adding that build pack, the ffmpeg error is not there, but still the song is not playing.

Comment: Ok, is There a different error? if the file doesn't play there must be some error printed to Heroku console

Comment: @benl134 No message in heroku console